# Interpolation producing weird result QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I have some points I want to interpolate.

Output:

[image]

Anybody got a good idea on this one?

Comment: What is the CRS of your point layer?

Comment: EPSG:4326, WGS 84

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? I remember in an early QGIS version, I had some issues interpolating points which had a CRS of EPSG:4326. Reprojecting it to a UTM CRS worked. But re-testing this on QGIS 2.18.3 using EPSG:4326 works fine.

Comment: okay I will update my 2.16.1 version and give feedback afterwards

Comment: I did not make an update but tried it with the reprojection which produced great results.

Comment: Nice one! Glad you got it working, will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One possible method would be to **reproject** your point layer from the *EPSG:4326* to a **UTM** CRS instead. Ofcourse, you would need to reconfigure the settings to satisfy your CRS units instead of using degrees.
- Another method (which worked for me) was to use the latest QGIS version (e.g. QGIS 2.18) as personally, I had issues with interpolating point layers which used the CRS EPSG:4326.